# Coupling between 1st and 2nd order phase transitions?

Tags: reference-request, ising-model, monte-carlo, statistical-thermodynamics, phase-transitions

I am seeking some models or references on how to couple, or what to take into consideration, while coupling first-order phase transitions (for magnetic systems) and second-order phase transitions, in regards to order and disorder in these systems.

[This is an example of such a system](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-018-0201-1?proof=true19#article-info).

Comment: Welcome to the site, interesting question but maybe you could provide a bit more detail. At present, one would need to dive into the paper to retrieve the relevant details (at least in my opinion) but this could probably be provided by you easily and also help in understanding your own problem.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by coupling 1st and 2nd order phase transitions? I think I will be able to answer if I know a bit more detail.